# Why does .NET Core allow using references' nuget packages without installing them?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependencies, nuget

.NET Core allows using project references' nuget packages e.g.

```
MainProject
 -LocalRef1
   -LocalRef2
     -Newtonsoft.Json
```

`MainProject` has a direct reference to `LocalRef1` which has a direct reference to `LocalRef2` and `LocalRef2` has the nuget package `Newtonsoft.Json` installed.

In `MainProject`, not only are we able to access `LocalRef2` members but also the `Newtonsoft.Json` package.

In .NET Framework we'd need to reference the projects and nuget package directly to access them.

Why has this changed? Is there any documentation describing how this works?

It seems to only work with local projects as in, we can't access nuget packages referenced in other nuget packages.

This can cause a lot of issues and increase complexity as it adds 'virtual' dependencies to projects, not to mention how easy it is to create circular references.

Is there a recommended set of best practices?

Comment: This is called "transitive dependencies", and it is not limited to .NET Core; a .NET Framework project *using the same build system* would work the same; and no, it isn't just limited to local packages - you *should* get all of the dependency tree automatically (this is intentional; there are even "meta-packages" that literally contain nothing *except* onward package dependencies)

Comment: @MarcGravell I couldn't reproduce this with .NET framework, what does 'using the same build system' mean?

Comment: by that I mean: a .NET Framework project using the new SDK-style csproj, but which happens to have `<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>` or `<TargetFrameworks>net462;net472;net48</TargetFrameworks>` (etc)